# implement a scroll on mouse move in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I want to implement a scroll on mouse move in jQuery.

The purpose of scroll is to view the complete image.. which has appeared as Modal Popup.

This image is present as Div's Background image.

I am able to move image up-down on mouse move using jQuery.
But the problem is the div's background continues to scroll event after complete image is scrolled.
I have to stop this from happening.

for reference u can see:-

http://zovi.com/california-dream-t-shirt-white--S123RNM84602#2

Click on the big image, a modal popup will appear. On scrolling, complete image is viewed without extra scrolling.

I am trying to achieve this.
Thanks in Advance..

Here is my code:-

Complete HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .backdrop
        {
            position: relative;
            height: 300px; /*could be anything really..*/
            width: 400px; /*could be anything really..*/
            border: 3px solid #6699ff;
            background: url('image/TShirt/tshirtpicZoom1.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;

        }

        .direction
        {
            position: absolute;
            width: 50%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .top
        {
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width:100%;

        }
        .bottom
        {
            left: 0;
            top: 50%;
            width:100%;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var x = 0,
        y = 0,
        rate = 0,
        maxspeed = 10;
            var backdrop = $('.backdrop');

            $('.direction', backdrop).mousemove(function (e) {
                var $this = $(this);
                var top = $this.is('.top');

                if (top) {
                    var h = $this.height();
                    rate = (h - e.pageY - $(this).offset().top + 1) / h;
                }
                else {
                    var h = $this.height();
                    rate = -(e.pageY - $(this).offset().top + 1) / h;
                }
            });

            backdrop.hover(
        function () {
            var scroller = setInterval(moveBackdrop, 10);
            $(this).data('scroller', scroller);
        },
        function () {
            var scroller = $(this).data('scroller');
            clearInterval(scroller);
        }
    );

            function moveBackdrop() {
                y += maxspeed * rate;
                var newpos = x + 'px ' + y + 'px';

                backdrop.css('background-position', newpos);
            }
        }); 

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="backdrop">
        <div class="direction top">
        </div>
        <div class="direction bottom">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution myself....

Here's what I did...

Take a Dummy image control and keep it hidden

```
<img id="DummyImage" class="hidden" />
```

Assign the image source to the dummy image control before calling modal popup i.e. on  `$('#BigImage')` click event.

Also make y and rate value 0

```
y = 0;
rate = 0;
$("#DummyImage").attr('src', imageSrc);
```

Now in the mouse move event i.e '`moveImageZoomBox`' function make the dummy image control visible and get the height of the image.

In the same mouse move event take to variables as '`scrollmin`' and '`scrollmax`' and then

`scrollmin=-(height of the image)`

```
scrollmax=(height of the image)/2
```

Now apply condition such the the value of should be between '`scrollmin`' and '`scrollmax`'

The '`moveImageZoomBox`' function will look like this:

```
function moveImageZoomBox() {
                y += maxspeed * rate;
                var ScrollYMin = 0;
                var ScrollYMax = 0;
                var tths = this;
                $("#DummyImage").show();

                ScrollYMin = -($("#DummyImage")[0].naturalHeight-300);//in order to stop scrolling whole image up
                ScrollYMax = $("#DummyImage")[0].naturalHeight / 2-200;//in order to stop scrolling whole image down

                $("#DummyImage").hide();

                var newpos = x + ' ' + y + 'px';
                if (y > ScrollYMin && y < ScrollYMax) {
                    imageZoomBox.css('background-position', newpos);
                }
                else {
                    y -= maxspeed * rate;
                }
            }
```